# Using a matrix values for determine turtles interactions in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Hello I am writing a code in which i put a population of turtles play rock-paper-scissor and depending of the payoff of the the matrix value for using one of the strategies, the turtles change his colors

```
   R   P  S
R[ 0  -1  1]
P[ 1   0 -1]
S[-1   1  0]
```

So first I assign the strategies with colors, let say rock is brown, paper is red and scissors are blue. So next, what i need to do is assign the values of the matrix to each strategy (color turtles) and if the payoff of using a strategies is less than 0 change the color of the turtle but what primitive can i use to do this?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the Prisoner's Dilemma models in the Sample Models section of NetLogo's Models Library, under Social Science. They're very much like what you describe.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the rock-paper-scissors game on the Modeling Commons.  E.g.,
http://modelingcommons.org/browse/one_model/2554

You left many aspects of your model unspecified.  E.g., are you doing random pairing of turtles who then play the game?  Assuming yes, you could proceed as follows.  Make a link between the any two turtles who will play a game, and ask the link to change their colors (based on their strategies).

You want to be careful not to ask turtles directly to change strategies/colors, since this will mean that after one turtle changes its strategy the other will see a different partner-strategy than the one played during the game. So first determine the new strategies for both players, and then assign them both.